# I would like to know what the following FORTRAN 77 code does

Tags: fortran, interpolation, fortran77

In a .f file there is code that does this:

```
real Bob, avar
...
avar = Bob( 8.3 )
...
```

Bob appears to be a function but it is declared at the beginning of the file as a real.

Then there is a .d file that has a reference to Bob. Also I know avar holds  a value that appears is interpolated, The problem is the interpolation is not always right.

```
Bob    John      35
-17.     -16.     -15.     -14.     -13.     -12.     -11.     -10.     -9.      -8.  
-7.      -6.      -5.      -4.      -3.      -2.      -1.       0.       1.       2.5  
 3.       4.       5.       6.5      7.       8.       9.       10.      11.      12.  
 13.      14.      15.      16.      17.  
 0.001    0.001    0.041    0.098    0.155    0.213    0.27     0.327    0.384    0.441   
 0.499    0.556    0.613    0.670    0.728    0.785    0.844    0.904    0.965    1.058   
 1.089    1.152    1.216    1.314    1.347    1.413    1.479    1.543    1.609    1.670   
 1.733    1.799    1.860    1.925    1.937
```

This is all legacy code. I did not write it. I am trying to fix it. My question consists of the following:

> What is this doing and how? What is a .d file?

I think it is trying to interpolate but I did not think you could do this (in this way) with FORTRAN 77.

Comment: your question is very unclear. is Bob a function? why you say that you do this, but then you don't know what it does? Where is the code you actually speak about in your question title? what is the relationship with the .d file ?

Comment: Please post more, real code, without the ... stuff.

Comment: well that is all the code that is relevant. 
the rest has nothing to do with this.

Comment: I have striped out all the other code and left just this and it  worked. So is it still a bad question our do you not know the answer ?

Comment: I think that the questions that Stefano Borini has asked are fair, you should answer them and then we should be able to answer yours.

Comment: I do not know if bob is a function ... that is part of my question. the code is what is pasted. minus the implicit none and the includes.


The .d file is the table. Oh and there is an end at the end.

I could paste 3000 lines of code that have nothing to do with this question (actually  I can't) or I could give you this snippet. A snippet that compiles with out the 2000 + other lines of code and has the functionality I am questioning.

Comment: BTW, Bob may well be both a a variable and a function - F77 allows that.

Comment: I am showing it! that is the code. I asked what it does!
I acutely know How to fix the problem with a interpolation function that I could call. My question is what is this doing! I am trying to figure out if this is a language construct in FORTRAN that I am not familiar with. I know what result it is giving me. I am trying to figure out what it is doing. I have never seen this before.

Comment: As far as the includes go John is a var that is in an include. The other includes do not have anything to do with this function/variable

Comment: @Paul - Okey. The first line declares Bob as a real variable, the second (or third, depends how you take it), calls a function Bob and gives its result to avar. That's all that can be with certanty said for this code. What interpolation it is doing, and whether it is doing it cannot be said. Also, I do not understand the last comment about interpolation - why couldn't it be done in fortran ? You could do it with a pen&paper if you wish. A .d file is, imho, just a file with a .d extension. Has nothing to do with fortran source as such.

Comment: Is your question whether "Bob" in the .d file implicitly declares a function? Well, you could simply try by renaming "Bob" to something else and see what happens (and do a case-insensitive grep on all files for "bob" to see where else it occurs).

Comment: divo that is something I will try. Thanks

Comment: interpolation can be done I know (see other comments). What I meant was by using just a table in a file like a .d file.

Comment: @Paul - what do you mean "by using just a table" - the table is just organized data; that has nothing to do with it. Numbers on a piece of paper.

Comment: Yes ... right ... I agree .. That is why I am puzzled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion. The answer is the system is using a proprietary macro c to FORTRAN program that does interpolation. This happens in the make file. I found by looking at some obscure documentation . Thanks everyone for their input. Sorry again for the terseness of it. I was not trying to be difficult. It was confusing to me with what I saw as well. It is sometimes difficult working with 30 year old legacy code bought from a different company. I am new to FORTRAN so I thought I was not seeing something I should have been seeing like a language feature I was unfamiliar with. I feel foolish. It did lead  me to dig deeper. Lesson learned.

Comment: Shouldn't there have been some calling interface in the fortran program, then ?

Comment: Man, how wild. I love that stuff. I'm starting to envy you. :-)

Comment: The calling code is created by the make file that calls a C program. It made a Bob_() function. Can not seem to find that yet. :) The code itself is run as part of another system. There is a lot of CRAP I have yet to figure out. Yes Nosrenda it is Fun :).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Bob is a function, that is getting the real value 8.3 passed to it, and is returniung a real that is stored in avar. But that's all that can be gleaned from the code you have posted.

Comment: Bob is not declared using syntax like real function bob(something)

Comment: A file with the extension .d? I'd take a wild guess it is a data file. F77 does not require or expect any specific file extensions.

Comment: Bob is not declared as  function IN THE CODE YOU POSTED - this is why we are all saying you need to post more code.

Comment: There is no code file that declares bob as a function hence my puzzlement. I looked at the whole UNIX box for any file that did that and came up empty. So you have all the info I have. I am looking at other possibilities at the moment.

Comment: Any USE statements in there, by any chance? Also, don't take this the wrong way or anything, but is there a specific (or not so specific reason) why you can't just post the whole thing somewhere ? Licence, security issues ? The process would go a lot faster than just guessing like this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the .d file contains some data that is nearly linear. Looks like experimental data. 35 is the number of points you have, then you have the x, and then the y.

Bob and John seems to be like some kind of string markers, or identifiers. They are probably used somewhere in the code to decide what to do with the data, or what kind of data they represent.

Bob seems like a function. Please note that you have two ways of declaring a function.

```
real function foo(a)
    implicit none
    real, intent(in) :: a
    foo = 3.0+a
end function

program test
   implicit none
   real foo, bar, a, b
   bar(b) = b+5.0

   a=foo(5.3)
   print *, a, bar(2.3)
end program
```

One is the explicit case (foo), where you return the value by assign to the variable named as the function itself.
The other case is "implicit" (don't know the formal name), see bar. You declare it as an "array" and then express how it should behave. Seen it very rarely, but it's a very compact writing.

Comment: I agree with all except no were in the code does it do that.

I am perplexed ... I will dig and get back.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the .d file has been created through that program? people leave a lot of garbage around.

Comment: I found the reason ... thanks ... see my answer to the question. I feel foolish.

Answer (score 0):

A .d file is probably some dope's way of abreviating .dat. He was too lazy to type the two extra characters. Old time programmers were like that.

It looks like you've got a simple interpolation function on a graph where "Bob" is the X axis spanning from -17 to +17 and "John" is a set of values in the Y direction corresponding to the Bob points. (Don't know what the 35 is for, since only 32 points are shown.)

The code is asking: for a value on the X axis, 8.3, what would be the interpolated value in the Y direction. In the linear form it would return .3 times the difference between 1.413 and 1.479. It could be a higher order interpolator but you don't show the code, so I assume the simplest.